# Access denied error while sending proposal to peer from java sdk

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to query the blockchain using the following code and getting the access denied error. also i am getting the same error while `sendTransactionProposal` method as well.

```
    UserContext adminUserContext = RegisterEnrollUser.registerAdminUser(Config.CA_ORG1_URL, Config.ORG1_MSP, Config.ORG1);

    FabricClient fabClient = new FabricClient(adminUserContext);

    ChannelClient channelClient = fabClient.createChannelClient(Config.CHANNEL_NAME);
    Channel channel = channelClient.getChannel();
    Peer peer = fabClient.getInstance().newPeer(Config.ORG1_PEER_0, Config.ORG1_PEER_0_URL);
    EventHub eventHub = fabClient.getInstance().newEventHub("eventhub01", Config.ORG1_PEER_0_URL_Eventhub);
    Orderer orderer = fabClient.getInstance().newOrderer(Config.ORDERER_NAME, Config.ORDERER_URL);
    channel.addPeer(peer);
    channel.addEventHub(eventHub);
    channel.addOrderer(orderer);
    channel.initialize();
    Collection<ProposalResponse> responsesQuery = channelClient.queryByChainCode("tmz", "queryAllEntries", null);
```

> Caused by: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer peer0.org1.example.com.  Status FAILURE, details: Sending proposal to peer0.org1.example.com failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNKNOWN, description=access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP], cause=null}

Following are logs for peer0.org1.example.com

Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) for identity.
WARN 2a11 [channel: mychannel] Client authorization revoked for deliver request from 
Failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy on channel [mychannel] with policy [/Channel/Application/Readers]: [Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining]

2018-06-14 21:05:11.545 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 2a12 Waiting for new SeekInfo from

2018-06-14 21:05:11.545 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 2a13 Attempting to read seek info message from

2018-06-14 21:05:11.609 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 2a14 Error reading from : rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

2018-06-14 21:05:11.609 UTC [common/deliverevents] func1 -> DEBU 2a15 Closing Deliver stream

Comment: I was getting this issue when I had not run the CreateChannel command.

java -cp blockchain-client.jar org.example.network.CreateChannel