# Getting below error when i run the invoke app written in javascript

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

i build this network with 1 CA, 2 orgs and 1 peer per org(docker-compose.yaml):

```
`version: '2'

networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
command: orderer
ports:
  - 7050:7050
volumes:
    - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg2
networks:
  - basic

 peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - basic
  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
     working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
     command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7071:7051
      - 7073:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - basic
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
     environment:
       - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
       - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
       - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
       - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
       - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
       - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
       - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
     volumes:
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./../chaincode/myChaincode/src/github.com:/opt/gopath/src/github.com
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
       - orderer.example.com
       - peer0.org1.example.com
       - peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
        - basic
```

i get no error when running this sh script:

```
set -ev
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=newnetwork 
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051" cli peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx

# Join peer0.org1.example.com and peer0.org2.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051" cli peer channel join -b mychannel.block

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051" cli peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

and i successfully create the channel, install and instantiate a chaincode on the channel in this way:

```
CC_NAME=ccOperation
CC_SRC_PATH=chaincode/CCOperation
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051" cli peer chaincode install -n $CC_NAME -v 1.0 -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" -l "$LANGUAGE"

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051" cli peer chaincode install -n $CC_NAME -v 1.0 -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" -l "$LANGUAGE"

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051" cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050  -C mychannel -n $CC_NAME -l "$LANGUAGE" -v 1.0 -c $INIT_STR -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```

now the question is: when i try to invoke the chaincode with a javascript application, the same that you can find in fabcar example (fabric-samples) using the 3 file:
enrollAdmin.js registerUser.js and invoke.js
i get the error below:

```
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
at new createStatusError (/home/mattia/Documenti/fabric-samples/app2Org1Peer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
at /home/mattia/Documenti/fabric-samples/app2Org1Peer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
Transaction proposal was bad
Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting...
```

anyone could help me please?
thanks in advance

Comment: i am getting the exact same error in java app. [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866075/access-denied-error-while-sending-proposal-to-peer-from-java-sdk). Have you installed the blockchain on the same machine as your app. and what fabric version are you using.

Comment: the app is running on the same pc where the network is built. The fabric version is  1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using cryptogen, so you'll actually need to explicitly set the private and public keys for the CA using the `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE` and `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE` variables.  You will want to use the file ending with `_sk` as the keyfile and the `pem` file as the fertile.